# Specular and diffuse reflection at the same time

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics, popular-science

if we know that tomatoes absorb all the light and reflect the red diffusely, how can we see the reflection of all the light specularly at the shinnig point? there isnt an absorption of other colors at that point? and how there is specular and diffuse reflection at the same time? (it is specular reflection of all the light because we can see the image of the light source)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've asked several things here.  Let me try:

1. The "white spot" is visible because the spectral absorption is far from 100%. Thus when the source is of significant intensity, enough light at all (or enough) wavelengths is reflected that the eye or the camera sees "white."
2. The skin of the tomato is neither perfectly diffuse ("Lambertian surface") nor perfectly specular.  It may help to think of it as a double-exposure or as a pair of surfaces.  The total reflectivity vs. emission angle is a mix of the two.

Comment: thank you so much , espacially for the key term "lambertian surface" , (about the tomato) so what happens is in diffuse reflection the light penetrate the object some wavelenghts gets absorbed , the remaining light gets relflected multiple times inside the object and comes out in all sorts of directions . and in specular reflection the light gets reflected at the surface, and reflect back with all its wavelenghts so it doesnt penetrate far enough to get absorbed . (please correct me if something wrong)

Comment: Q1 : if this is true then the difference between specular and diffuse reflection is a matter of depth , and its all about the absorbing/reflecting properties of an object , but what i hear all the time is diffuse=rough surface , specular=smooth surface , im a little bit confused , im not sure i know how to define specular from diffuse, is the roughness/smothness irrelevant ?

Comment: Q2 : why the image of the light source in the "shine" is blurry ?

Comment: sorry if i asked you a lot or wasted your time , but i have a lot of questions without answers ,  nobody answers me, and i dont want to just move on because i know its gonna hold me down in the future

Comment: @Badr  One more suggestion:  look up "BRDF" , bidirectional reflectance distribution function.  That may give you some insight as well as ideas about what else to read up on

Comment: i serched up a lillte bit and this is what i uderstood ,most part of the light incident on the tomato is transmetted and getting effected by the tomato's properties and reflected back diffusly as red  . the other part is reflected at the surface specularly but due to the imperfections on the tomato's surface , the image of the light source is not "mirror like" and more blurry.